# Eclipse Projectdependency on multiple src directories

Tags: eclipse, gradle, java-9, eclipse-neon

today I have a special problem which already took me a while at the debugger.
I have two projects Project A and Project B.
Project A has multiple src-directories.

```
src
├───main
│   └───java
└───generated
    └───java
```

both are recognized by eclipse as actual src directories. Both will be compiled to bin which looks like this:

```
bin
├───main
└───generated
```

Project B has a Project-dependencie on Project A.
And now comes the strange part: When I look for a class from `Project A/src/main/java` via `Class.forName()` inside Project B it will be found. When i look for a class from `Project A/src/generated/java` I get a ClassNotFound exception.

I would be very glad if you could point out a way to tell eclipse to create a dependencie on both src-directories.

btw, just in case it is important: I am using java 9.
and here is an excerpt of .classpath from Project B

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/Project A"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a bug of your maybe outdated Eclipse IDE. Can you reproduce this issue with [a preview version of Eclipse Photon](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) (with Neon it should not be possible to use Java 9, at least Oxygen.1a is required to write Java 9 code; Neon has been released 2016, Oxygen is the current release and Photon will be released next week)?

Comment: @howlger i made a mistake, i was not using neon but oxygen. I did as you asked and tried to replicate the behaviour in photon RC3. The problem is still existing there.

Comment: Maybe it's the run configuration (try to delete it and try again _Run As > ..._) or the `gradle.build` (does it contain `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`?) is not in sync. As a workaround you can use different source folder but only one output folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug of Eclipse, Gradle or a combination of both. Try to delete the run configuration and restart the application. Make also sure the `gradle.build` file is in sync with the Eclipse project. If all this doesn't help, you can **use a single output folder as workaround**:

- **Manually in *Project > Properties: Java Build Path*, in the tab *Source***:

  1. **Uncheck** the checkbox ***Allow output folders for source folders***
  2. In the field ***Default output folder*** enter **`bin/main`**
- or via following **`gradle.build` snippet**:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse.classpath.file.whenMerged {
    entries.find { it.path == 'src/main/java' }.output = 'bin/main'
    entries.find { it.path == 'src/generated/java' }.output = 'bin/main'
}
```

Comment: you are a genius, deleting the runconfiguration did the job. I cant believe I have spend 10 hours on that problem, researching classloaders and all kinds of stuff, when the only problem is a damaged runconfiguration. Thank you very much.